# Short story about invading another world, twist is the 'futuristic' invaders are actually conquistadores?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, history

I'm looking for a short scifi story about invaders with futuristic sounding technology - *blasters* and *chargers* - invading a new world after having conquered many others and attacking the civilisation they find there.

The twist being these are conquistadores with *guns* and *horses*, invading the Americas.

Comment: So are there any genunie science fiction elements in this story then, or just the _illusion_ of such elements? Also, if there _is_ genuine sci-fi in this story, then when did you read it, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: It sounds like it was written to deceive the reader into thinking it was SF. I think it counts as on-topic for the forum.

Comment: @LogicDictates yep, just the illusion. Pete is correct.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is Randall Garrett's [*Despoilers of the Golden Empire*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/24091/24091-h/24091-h.htm) (published in the March 1959 *Astounding Science Fiction* as by "David Gordon").  It's a perfect match to your question and tells the story of Pizarro's conquest of the Incas using language which *sounds* like an interstellar invasion.

Comment: From the same author, in the same magazine, a couple years earlier: the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241217/looking-for-the-title-of-a-very-old-sci-fi-short-story-where-a-human-deters-an-a): a story in which the *protagonist* does what the author is doing here.

Comment: Can you provide another source for the book, preferably an ISBN? The site blocks access for users with an IP Address of my country.

Comment: @Polygnome Is this link any better? https://web.archive.org/web/20210216140533/http://www.gutenberg.org/files/24091/24091-h/24091-h.htm

Comment: I'd argue it gives the game away a bit with making the Power Metal explicitly gold.